# Showing that a particular second-order IVP has a particular Fibonacci-related power series solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I'm given the IVP

> $$ y'' = y' + y, \qquad y(0) = 0, \qquad y'(0)=1 $$

I need to deduce a power series solution of the form $$ y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{F_n}{n!} x^n, $$ for this IVP, where the coefficients are Fibonacci numbers defined by $F_0 = 1, F_1 = 1$ and $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$ for $n > 1$.

We have that $$ y'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n!} F_n x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{F_n}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1} $$ and $$ y''(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{F_n}{(n-2)!} x^{n-2} $$ I plugged this in the ODE: \begin{align*} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{F_n}{(n-2)!} x^{n-2} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{F_n}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{F_n}{n!} x^n = 0 \end{align*} By the identity theorem, this gives me the general recurrence relation \begin{align*} F_n \bigg( \frac{1}{(n-2)!} - \frac{1}{(n-1)!} - \frac{1}{n!} \bigg) = 0 \end{align*} or, equivalently \begin{align*} F_n \bigg( \frac{n^2 - 2n - 1}{n!} \bigg) = 0 \end{align*} But then I'm not sure how to proceed. I think I need to show that the coefficients are actually Fibonacci numbers, by showing that $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$ holds. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you have to assemble equal powers of $x$, this requires index shifts in the series.

Comment: Ah right. Alright, I just did that. This gives me $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigg( \frac{F_{n+2} - F_{n+1} - F_n}{n!} \bigg) = 0$. Then can I just conclude that $F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_n $ ? This looks circular reasoning to me.

Comment: You should start with unknown coefficients and then from initial conditions and power series identification conclude that the coefficient sequence actually is the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Philippe_Marie_Binet) for [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio) might come in handy here, especially since the IVP admits a closed form solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{F_n}{(n-2)!} x^{n-2} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{F_n}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{F_n}{n!} x^n = 0$$

You need to rewrite these series by shifting the indices:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{F_{n+2}}{(n)!} x^{n} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{F_{n+1}}{(n)!} x^{n} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{F_n}{n!} x^n = 0$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}-F_n}{n!}x^n$$

In particular $F_{2}=F_{1}+F_{0}$. You can then show that $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$ in general (this might require a bit of proof).

EDIT: since this last step is maybe the confusing part, let's write out the series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}-F_n}{n!}x^n$$

$$=(F_2-F_1-F_0)+(F_3-F_2-F_1)x+\frac{F_4-F_3-F_2}{2!}x^2+\cdots$$

and evaluating at $x=0$ gives $F_2=F_1+F_0$. Differentiating and evaluating at $x=0$ gives $F_3=F_2+F_1$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Let $$y = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n$$ be a power series solution to the given i.v.p.,
$$y'' = y' + y, \qquad y(0) = 0, \qquad y(1) = 1.$$

Now, formally we have
\begin{align*}
y'  &= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(n - 1)!} x^{n - 1} \\
y'' &= \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(n - 2)!} x^{n - 2}
\end{align*}

In order to solve for the coefficients $a_n$ we reindex these infinite sums so that the generic terms have the form $b_n x^n$ (so that, after substitution, we can extract a factor of $x^n$ for each term):
\begin{align*}
y'  &= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n + 1}}{n!} x^n \\
y'' &= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n + 2}}{n!} x^n
\end{align*}

> **Additional hint** Substituting gives $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n + 2}}{n!} x^n = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n + 1}}{n!} x^n - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n . $$ Formally, rearranging give $$0 = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} (a_{n + 2} - a_{n + 1} - a_n) x^n .$$ Extracting the coefficients gives $$a_{n + 2} - a_{n + 1} - a_n = 0$$ for all $n$, but this is nearly the characterization of the Fibonacci sequence; it remains to compute $a_0, a_1$ (using the initial conditions).